# How to make an object clickable depending on player distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make an item in my scene clickable but only when the player is near the item. In my script I make the item in question go automatically to an empty GameObject that is child of my Player in the hierarchy to define the position but the click is able as soon as the camera have it framed. I'm using the character controller provided in the 2d physics and not a 2drigidbody so I'm even more confused because I can't use a collider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make anything clickable I would recommend [`IPointerXHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interfaces (replace X with `Click`, `Enter`, `Exit`, `Down`, `Up`, etc).

Note:

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow click detection. For click detection on **non-UI** GameObjects, ensure a [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) is attached to the Camera.

If you only want to click `IPointerClickHandler` is enough. If you want some visiual feedback like changing colors etc you'll have to expand it with at least `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler`.

```
public class MyClickable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in order to get the distance between two obects you can simply use [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) e.g. with a ceratin threshold

```
// configure those e.g. in the Inspector
public float distanceThreshold;
public Transofrm playerTransform;
public Transform itemTransform;
```

and than use something like

```
if(Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, itemTransform.position) <= distanceThreshold)
{
    ...
}
```

so if you directly implement this into the `MyClickable` you could do visual feedback also in `Update` something like

```
public class MyClickable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public float distanceThreshold;
    public Transofrm playerTransform;

    // this gives you an event you can configure in the Inspector
    // exactly like you would with a button
    public UnityEvent onClick;

    private bool isInRange;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // if too far away do nothing
        if(Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, transform.position) > distanceThreshold) return;

        ....

        onClick.Invoke();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, transform.position) <= distanceThreshold)
        {
            // e.g. make object green
        }
        else
        {
            // e.g. make object grey
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I made it a little different because I'm using OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp... but your "if"logic with the distanceThreshold worked perfectly with what I already had so thanks for your time and help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can have both a character controller and a collider on a gameobject (at least a trigger collider).

Then instead of whatever you're using to detect the click, you should use in an Update loop something like `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)`, and use a raycast where you can specify the length of the ray. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Thanks I knew of the existence of the docs. but as a total noob I find a little hard to search on it because I'm not sure where to find the things I'm looking for but I guess I'm going to give it a full check to become a little more familiar with the terms. Thanks for your time and suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the onMouseDown() method. If you have a collider or trigger attached to your gameObject, onMouseDown() will detect mouse clicks on the object. Then in then body of onMouseDown() you can test if it is in range.

This is an example script how it could work:

```
public class ItemClickable : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;        // player-transform reference (depends if you have a singleton or not)
    public float range;             // radius (maybe you have a range or radius already set in your player instance)

    void Start()
    {
        // Setup for your references        
    }


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {   
        // Checks if the item is in the range of the player
        if ((player.position-gameObject.transform.position).magnitude < range) // Vector3.Distance() is also possible
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // or do whatever you want in here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually get to something very similar to your suggestion reading the answers above...maybe coming to read this before would make it faster hahaha thanks for your help and time I really appreciate it.

Comment: The problem with OnMouseDown() is it will only works for PC + Mouse, which can be inconveniant. In my project you can toggle VR and if I went for OnMouseDown() I would have needed to do everything differently to do the same thing. For the sake of portability I highly recommend my method.

Comment: @Jichael: But in the question the 2D aspect was mentioned, so I give the default way for doing this. And if you know you need an integration for VR of course the approach is a different one but this wasn't part of the question. The probability of making a coding mistake if you inexperienced with raycasting or the 3D-room and the transformation from the different spaces(even with the premade functions) is higher in my opinion.